# Plotting multiple box plots unevenly over an even x axis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph that has the box plots for bacteria amounts (the value in the dictionary) collected at certain locations over a river. Each location has its own river mile (the key in the dictionary).
I want a graph that looks like this:

[image]

But the graph I've produced looks like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
river_dict = {74.9: [230.0, 43.0, 29.0, 44.0, 100.0, 44.0, 53.0, 7.0, 54.0, 29.0, 18.0, 41.0, 80.0, 27.0, 110.0, 59.0, 5.0, 140.0, 130.0, 80.0, 10.0, 12.0, 130.0, 58.0, 23.0, 40.0, 45.0, 97.0, 32.0, 50.0, 60.0, 13.0, 27.0, 120.0, 13.0, 57.0, 1.0, 38.0, 9.0, 160.0, 18.0, 32.0, 43.0, 19.0, 43.0, 60.0, 5.0, 38.0, 41.0, 27.0, 5.0, 12.0, 40.0, 29.0, 43.0, 9.0, 54.0, 42.0, 7.0, 120.0, 34.0, 120.0, 42.0, 47.0, 9.0, 90.0, 14.0, 150.0, 290.0, 16.0, 53.0, 100.0, 16.0, 190.0, 150.0, 120.0, 93.0, 53.0, 130.0, 8.0, 8.0, 26.0, 20.0, 120.0, 40.0, 57.0, 6.0, 35.0, 140.0, 110.0, 23.0, 47.0, 46.0, 130.0, 7.0, 150.0, 60.0, 29.0, 27.0, 150.0, 67.0, 10.0, 35.0, 54.0, 87.0, 24.0, 190.0, 41.0, 28.0, 13.0, 160.0, 48.0, 32.0, 130.0, 260.0, 150.0, 21.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 28.0, 180.0, 110.0, 160.0, 48.0, 7.0, 45.0], 
78.1: [140.0, 16.0, 60.0, 57.0, 20.0, 25.0, 24.0, 11.0, 14.0, 130.0, 53.0, 27.0, 23.0, 340.0, 320.0, 30.0, 31.0, 31.0, 7.0, 21.0, 30.0, 8.0, 110.0, 22.0, 13.0, 580.0, 31.0, 80.0, 60.0, 100.0, 54.0, 38.0, 170.0, 5.0, 37.0, 43.0, 40.0, 220.0, 49.0, 290.0, 17.0, 180.0, 8.0, 53.0, 12.0, 70.0, 30.0, 40.0, 21.0, 100.0, 12.0, 270.0, 370.0, 310.0, 16.0, 22.0, 170.0, 80.0, 13.0, 20.0, 24.0, 150.0, 2.0, 200.0, 60.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 51.0, 420.0, 180.0, 190.0, 140.0, 550.0, 50.0, 40.0, 29.0, 28.0, 220.0, 6.0, 93.0, 63.0, 47.0, 87.0, 60.0, 37.0, 27.0, 200.0, 60.0, 27.0, 33.0, 160.0, 60.0, 140.0, 370.0, 31.0, 22.0, 14.0, 140.0, 40.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.0, 100.0, 60.0, 150.0, 17.0, 50.0, 28.0, 47.0, 120.0, 37.0, 16.0, 77.0, 6.0, 53.0, 32.0, 160.0, 23.0, 57.0, 160.0, 44.0, 380.0, 19.0], 
122.4: [170.0, 32.0, 40.0, 26.0, 120.0, 32.0, 400.0, 180.0, 12.0, 57.0, 57.0, 46.0, 60.0, 400.0, 36.0, 140.0, 390.0, 80.0, 16.0, 57.0, 120.0, 130.0, 38.0, 420.0, 110.0, 210.0, 56.0, 130.0, 170.0, 47.0, 67.0, 20.0, 140.0, 60.0, 170.0, 140.0, 540.0, 24.0, 170.0, 60.0, 340.0, 83.0, 26.0, 22.0, 97.0, 28.0, 140.0, 97.0, 17.0, 47.0, 52.0, 26.0, 21.0, 13.0, 37.0, 32.0, 7.0, 10.0, 87.0, 190.0, 58.0, 5.0, 39.0, 27.0, 23.0, 80.0, 140.0, 24.0, 240.0, 110.0, 7.0, 27.0, 110.0, 28.0, 11.0, 20.0, 47.0, 31.0, 590.0, 70.0, 110.0, 51.0, 83.0, 67.0, 53.0, 28.0, 67.0, 44.0, 34.0, 45.0, 120.0, 54.0, 410.0, 110.0, 35.0, 150.0, 27.0, 9.0, 83.0, 26.0, 190.0, 38.0, 40.0, 150.0, 280.0, 500.0, 18.0, 270.0, 190.0, 180.0, 36.0, 22.0, 390.0, 18.0, 360.0, 110.0, 73.0, 31.0, 87.0, 160.0, 470.0, 21.0, 33.0, 1800.0, 180.0, 420.0, 10.0, 12.0, 150.0, 160.0, 60.0], 
84.0: [200.0, 28.0, 11.0, 60.0, 50.0, 80.0, 110.0, 17.0, 26.0, 1.0, 120.0, 38.0, 180.0, 51.0, 25.0, 43.0, 13.0, 23.0, 4.0, 6.0, 33.0, 54.0, 7.0, 48.0, 24.0, 15.0, 39.0, 56.0, 24.0, 13.0, 18.0, 73.0, 9.0, 100.0, 56.0, 23.0, 40.0, 51.0, 22.0, 140.0, 14.0, 67.0, 17.0, 340.0, 26.0, 41.0, 17.0, 14.0, 10.0, 51.0, 400.0, 52.0, 34.0, 360.0, 90.0, 37.0, 140.0, 70.0, 36.0, 40.0, 540.0, 29.0, 15.0, 25.0, 73.0, 170.0, 5.0, 300.0, 46.0, 12.0, 23.0, 130.0, 160.0, 160.0, 270.0, 36.0, 200.0, 30.0, 190.0, 21.0, 24.0, 40.0, 38.0, 18.0, 210.0, 7.0, 30.0, 57.0, 330.0, 130.0, 13.0, 60.0, 150.0, 83.0, 40.0, 60.0, 13.0, 130.0, 23.0, 90.0, 43.0, 19.0, 23.0, 47.0, 97.0, 13.0, 4.0, 33.0, 7.0, 56.0, 180.0, 100.0, 5.0, 110.0, 320.0, 110.0, 140.0, 59.0, 23.0, 10.0, 58.0, 120.0, 19.0, 97.0, 11.0, 30.0, 33.0, 390.0, 340.0, 190.0, 420.0, 23.0], 
110.7: [37.0, 50.0, 400.0, 40.0, 26.0, 110.0, 270.0, 120.0, 24.0, 35.0, 16.0, 25.0, 100.0, 48.0, 26.0, 110.0, 31.0, 410.0, 140.0, 18.0, 97.0, 24.0, 570.0, 230.0, 250.0, 170.0, 120.0, 93.0, 170.0, 73.0, 480.0, 240.0, 360.0, 35.0, 170.0, 420.0, 100.0, 130.0, 93.0, 30.0, 43.0, 140.0, 29.0, 50.0, 57.0, 43.0, 80.0, 22.0, 50.0, 160.0, 44.0, 48.0, 21.0, 43.0, 32.0, 22.0, 21.0, 130.0, 110.0, 14.0, 120.0, 32.0, 30.0, 45.0, 34.0, 310.0, 37.0, 14.0, 42.0, 25.0, 51.0, 590.0, 18.0, 67.0, 70.0, 29.0, 90.0, 770.0, 27.0, 160.0, 35.0, 100.0, 170.0, 77.0, 190.0, 35.0, 63.0, 18.0, 43.0, 35.0, 77.0, 80.0, 33.0, 530.0, 110.0, 140.0, 160.0, 10.0, 26.0, 120.0, 420.0, 130.0, 33.0, 30.0, 48.0, 67.0, 100.0, 390.0, 33.0, 43.0, 480.0, 15.0, 120.0, 77.0, 100.0, 37.0, 550.0, 130.0, 87.0, 120.0, 100.0, 220.0, 2.0, 180.0, 60.0, 160.0, 27.0, 41.0, 10.0, 35.0], 
100.2: [24.0, 190.0, 67.0, 430.0, 150.0, 49.0, 40.0, 410.0, 420.0, 38.0, 30.0, 290.0, 280.0, 150.0, 160.0, 380.0, 200.0, 38.0, 110.0, 97.0, 390.0, 290.0, 160.0, 140.0, 73.0, 240.0, 73.0, 160.0, 56.0, 4400.0, 260.0, 170.0, 230.0, 110.0, 310.0, 48.0, 46.0, 80.0, 55.0, 73.0, 560.0, 39.0, 420.0, 140.0, 120.0, 140.0, 93.0, 130.0, 330.0, 300.0, 53.0, 52.0, 140.0, 70.0, 35.0, 460.0, 180.0, 330.0, 470.0, 27.0, 60.0, 180.0, 47.0, 380.0, 150.0, 130.0, 97.0, 240.0, 290.0, 40.0, 60.0, 450.0, 150.0, 260.0, 140.0, 54.0, 100.0, 120.0, 63.0, 29.0, 53.0, 320.0, 80.0, 150.0, 57.0, 180.0, 510.0, 310.0, 41.0, 140.0, 280.0, 150.0, 43.0, 93.0, 100.0, 320.0, 430.0, 230.0, 480.0, 39.0, 53.0, 520.0, 180.0, 360.0, 2000.0, 40.0, 170.0, 57.0, 480.0, 280.0, 340.0, 67.0, 24.0, 540.0, 390.0, 200.0, 83.0, 350.0, 130.0, 310.0], 
87.5: [38.0, 350.0, 60.0, 22.0, 900.0, 14.0, 38.0, 32.0, 600.0, 23.0, 8.0, 83.0, 140.0, 22.0, 42.0, 28.0, 57.0, 30.0, 39.0, 7.0, 46.0, 140.0, 100.0, 6.0, 30.0, 150.0, 67.0, 310.0, 31.0, 60.0, 80.0, 120.0, 19.0, 57.0, 110.0, 14.0, 180.0, 400.0, 190.0, 200.0, 10.0, 60.0, 90.0, 55.0, 50.0, 21.0, 41.0, 87.0, 10.0, 25.0, 23.0, 180.0, 21.0, 310.0, 28.0, 13.0, 160.0, 30.0, 50.0, 5.0, 18.0, 340.0, 28.0, 230.0, 20.0, 48.0, 34.0, 160.0, 53.0, 200.0, 500.0, 19.0, 97.0, 25.0, 190.0, 40.0, 63.0, 140.0, 330.0, 120.0, 24.0, 340.0, 530.0, 28.0, 120.0, 210.0, 21.0, 200.0, 13.0, 120.0, 16.0, 170.0, 420.0, 110.0, 240.0, 27.0, 73.0, 190.0, 130.0, 420.0, 160.0, 67.0, 47.0, 44.0, 13.0, 23.0, 8.0, 90.0, 50.0, 25.0, 220.0, 50.0, 190.0, 160.0, 73.0, 490.0, 14.0, 26.0, 46.0, 19.0, 110.0, 330.0, 170.0, 47.0, 120.0, 30.0, 13.0], 
93.2: [35.0, 110.0, 1100.0, 430.0, 35.0, 77.0, 83.0, 150.0, 530.0, 43.0, 50.0, 60.0, 77.0, 130.0, 67.0, 140.0, 27.0, 350.0, 140.0, 220.0, 13.0, 200.0, 21.0, 330.0, 31.0, 47.0, 160.0, 33.0, 240.0, 110.0, 93.0, 30.0, 280.0, 210.0, 49.0, 180.0, 63.0, 37.0, 150.0, 24.0, 54.0, 19.0, 23.0, 130.0, 28.0, 360.0, 100.0, 28.0, 80.0, 200.0, 220.0, 380.0, 160.0, 23.0, 220.0, 29.0, 170.0, 97.0, 140.0, 41.0, 100.0, 80.0, 43.0, 55.0, 16.0, 110.0, 57.0, 90.0, 60.0, 180.0, 110.0, 9.0, 60.0, 49.0, 160.0, 47.0, 170.0, 35.0, 110.0, 200.0, 530.0, 140.0, 600.0, 420.0, 32.0, 130.0, 230.0, 73.0, 180.0, 70.0, 48.0, 83.0, 220.0, 460.0, 130.0, 17.0, 280.0, 320.0, 17.0, 100.0, 27.0, 29.0, 210.0, 450.0, 400.0, 210.0, 310.0, 48.0, 570.0, 130.0, 40.0, 140.0, 170.0, 130.0, 28.0, 56.0, 97.0, 500.0, 25.0, 360.0, 550.0], 
104.75: [14.0, 27.0, 220.0, 38.0, 150.0, 120.0, 180.0, 130.0, 35.0, 350.0, 20.0, 130.0, 60.0, 18.0, 47.0, 220.0, 150.0, 400.0, 100.0, 21.0, 97.0, 83.0, 130.0, 33.0, 16.0, 60.0, 540.0, 34.0, 220.0, 520.0, 29.0, 40.0, 23.0, 40.0, 340.0, 150.0, 100.0, 190.0, 130.0, 46.0, 380.0, 170.0, 80.0, 180.0, 45.0, 63.0, 60.0, 170.0, 25.0, 170.0, 80.0, 130.0, 140.0, 140.0, 41.0, 87.0, 150.0, 120.0, 190.0, 130.0, 42.0, 580.0, 56.0, 22.0, 43.0, 490.0, 290.0, 440.0, 38.0, 170.0, 31.0, 36.0, 190.0, 93.0, 550.0, 190.0, 21.0, 140.0, 520.0, 35.0, 540.0, 280.0, 21.0, 5.0, 47.0, 60.0, 160.0, 120.0, 28.0, 43.0, 1700.0, 30.0, 77.0, 13.0, 49.0, 520.0, 33.0, 110.0, 170.0, 200.0, 50.0, 34.0, 240.0, 70.0, 120.0, 42.0, 150.0, 42.0, 100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 97.0, 110.0, 87.0, 52.0, 160.0, 270.0], 
71.0: [120.0, 100.0, 170.0, 160.0, 27.0, 87.0, 490.0, 19.0, 12.0, 36.0, 230.0, 53.0, 52.0, 48.0, 36.0, 27.0, 56.0, 27.0, 29.0, 54.0, 130.0, 56.0, 21.0, 22.0, 14.0, 44.0, 55.0, 10.0, 120.0, 130.0, 8.0, 24.0, 30.0, 32.0, 5.0, 130.0, 45.0, 34.0, 10.0, 27.0, 160.0, 35.0, 13.0, 40.0, 34.0, 140.0, 30.0, 16.0, 17.0, 36.0, 180.0, 140.0, 180.0, 130.0, 35.0, 140.0, 8.0, 110.0, 80.0, 22.0, 170.0, 47.0, 36.0, 50.0, 34.0, 21.0, 15.0, 11.0, 17.0, 7.0, 13.0, 300.0, 32.0, 9.0, 180.0, 30.0, 110.0, 21.0, 47.0, 31.0, 48.0, 30.0, 57.0, 7.0, 180.0, 200.0, 83.0, 60.0, 30.0, 56.0, 240.0, 110.0, 59.0, 56.0, 43.0, 200.0, 100.0, 16.0, 43.0, 60.0, 46.0, 120.0, 12.0, 27.0, 27.0, 47.0, 60.0, 60.0, 220.0, 31.0, 100.0, 80.0, 26.0, 80.0, 22.0, 21.0, 500.0, 43.0, 8.0, 3.0, 63.0, 250.0, 170.0, 39.0, 8.0, 55.0, 7.0, 16.0, 10.0], 
117.8: [12.0, 21.0, 27.0, 21.0, 32.0, 21.0, 21.0, 120.0, 15.0, 240.0, 83.0, 12.0, 32.0, 16.0, 18.0]}


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.boxplot(river_dict.values(),showfliers=False)

ax.set_title("Fecal Coliform in the Delaware River")
ax.set_xlabel('\nRiver Mile')
ax.set_ylabel('Fecal Coliform Amount')

ax.set_xticklabels(river_dict.keys())

plt.show()
```

EDIT:

You can add positions to your boxplots in the second argument:

```py
ax.boxplot(river_dict.values(),positions=[*riverbacteria_dict.keys()],showfliers=False)
```

But now I'm not sure how to fix the x-axis to set it to what I want?
(I want the x-axis labels to be [70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115,120,125])

[image: Almost finished]

EDIT & Finished Graphs:

I completed the graph :) Here's the code for anyone who wants to use it later:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()


line_props = dict(color="b",linewidth=1)
medianprops = dict(color="black",linewidth=1.5)
ax.boxplot(riverbacteria_dict.values(),positions=[*riverbacteria_dict.keys()],showfliers=False,
           boxprops=line_props,whiskerprops=line_props,medianprops=medianprops,widths=.6)

ax.set_xticks(range(70, 126, 5))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(70, 126, 5))

ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.set_yticks(range(0,1001,200))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which='major')
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='major')
ax.yaxis.label.set_color('blue')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='blue')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax.set_title(bacteria+" in the Delaware River",weight='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('River Mile')
ax.set_ylabel(bacteria+' concentration (CFU/100mL)',weight='bold')

ax2.plot(*zip(*sorted(riverpercent_dict.items())),color='red',marker = 'o')

ax2.set_yticks(range(0,101,20))
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
ax2.set_ylabel('Percent of Samples that meet the Target: '+ str(target[bacteria]),weight='bold')
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('red')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: Final Graph]

Comment: Call `ax.set_xticks(range(70, 126, 5))` and then `ax.set_xticklabels(range(70, 126, 5))`?

Comment: Optionally you can make the boxes a bit wider: `ax.boxplot(river_dict.values(), positions=[*river_dict.keys()], widths=3)`